# Splitting array in substrings and echoing them inside divs, jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am coding a simple counter that uses the current date and ads some numbers to it. I want each digit of the final number to be displayed in its own div so I could style them. Here is the code I am working with. I am getting a 'Undefined' is not a function (evaluating('y.split("")') error, so I don't know if the code I made is completely broken or just this line is not working.

```
var counter = setInterval(timedCount,2000);
    function timedCount()
        {
        var x;
        var y;
        var arrDigit;
        var d=new Date();
        x=d.getTime();
        y=(Math.floor((x-928713600000)/1000))*16-61447952;
        var arrDigit = y.split(""); // this is the error line
        jQuery.each(arrDigit, function(){
                $("#counter").text('<div class="counter-digit">' + this + '</div>');
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your y is an int. you need to make it string.

Try:

```
function timedCount()
{
    var x, y, arrDigit;
    var html='';
    x = new Date().getTime();
    y=(Math.floor((x-928713600000)/1000))*16-61447952;
    var arrDigit = y.toString().split(""); // this is the error line

    $(arrDigit).each(function(){
        html += '<div class="counter-digit">' + this + '</div>');
    });
    $("#counter").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

split is a function that uses a string (not an array or int) and gives an array:

```
var s = "1,2,3";
console.log(s.split(",")); // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I would give an array to jquery each created using push():

```
var a = [];
a.push(1);
a.push(2);
a.push(3);
console.log(a); // [1,2,3]
```